# What is required to get a BSD-sockets-based program to do LAN networking under Emscripten?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, emscripten

Background:  I've got an C++/Qt-based application that communicates with servers on the user's LAN.  It uses non-blocking TCP and UDP sockets, and the networking is implemented via calls to the BSD sockets API (i.e. `socket()`/`send()`/`recv()`/`select()`/etc).  It all works well.

The other day, just for fun, I decided to recompile the application using [emscripten](https://emscripten.org), so that it could run as a WebAssembly app inside a web browser.

This worked surprisingly well -- within an hour or two, I had my app up and running inside Google Chrome.  However, the app's usefulness in this configuration is severely limited by the fact that it isn't able to connect to any servers -- presumably this is because it is running in a restricted/sandboxed environment.

If I wanted to pursue this line of development beyond the clever-hack-demo stage and try to make it useful, I would need to find a way for my program to discover and connect to servers on the user's LAN.

My question is:  is that functionality at all possible for a Emscripten/WebAssembly-based app to perform?  If so, what steps would I need to take?  (i.e. would it require upgrading the LAN's servers to handle WebSocket-based connections?  Would it require adding some sort of proxy server to run on the web server that the web page was served from?  Is UDP even a thing in a web-app context?  Are there other hoops that would also have to be jumped through?)

Comment: No such sockets in the context of the browser but VM on the host, I presume. So, is this question is more of proper VM context? More of Docker-type question? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: @AlexanderV nothing related to Docker is going on here; I've never used Docker and everything is running directly on my Mac.  (where "everything" == Google Chrome, a bare-bones web server I'm using to serve up the WebAssembly code to Google Chrome, and of course my Qt app, running inside the web page inside Google Chrome)

Comment: I read "it is running in a restricted/sandboxed environment", "beyond the clever-hack-demo stage", "upgrading servers". Environment it is. Not much with Docker or other container is going on yet but otherwise how else many instances of such type of web app will be supported on the host?

Comment: The restricted/sandboxed environment I was referring to is the environment in which JavaScript scripts (and their WebAssembly cousins) run in, when running inside a web browser.  AFAIK there are limits on what a JavaScript program can do, otherwise any web page you visit could start trying to scan your local network, etc.  Note that my program is (and will be) running inside the web browser, not on the web server.

Comment: Ok. I have a misconception with associating WebAssembly with WebGL too closely. I thought that thing improves WebGL but it is in container of web-browser. Hm.